# How to build a react application using gulp task?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, gulp

It possible to build react application (component) located to the project root using gulp task?

```
/dist
/public
/src
/reactcomponent <-- this is what I need to build using gulp
.gulpfile.js
```

My target from the described task is to build the whole project using only one command line instead of building the project to dist folder then build the reactcomponent and move it to dist the folder.

> Moving the react built folder to dist file was successfully done using the following code

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "node scripts/build.js && mv build ../dist/goalcalculator",
  ...
},
```

so what I'm looking for:

```
gulp.task("build", [
 "assets:dist",
 "image:min",
 "js:uglify",
 "robots:dist",
 "deeplinking:dist",
 "sitemap:dist",
 "css:dist",
 "html:dist",
 "htmlMobile:dist",
 "index:dist",
 --> Add new task that invoke the react build script above
]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you might need [babel](https://babeljs.io/)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox How can I use babel to solve this issue

Comment: There’s a section on the website which explains how to use gulp to compile JavaScript. There should also be docs on using it with react as well.

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-js-tutorial-pt-2-building-react-applications-with-gulp-and-browserify/